# Add columns to a TVirtualTreeView

Tags: c++builder-6

I am adding data to a `TVirtualTreeView` from a query, but I need to be able to add or remove columns according to the sorting parameters that the user decides.

In `TListView`, I am used to using this code to define columns:

```cpp
TListColumn * pColumn;
pColumn = ListView1->Columns->Add();
```

but in `TVirtualStringTree` using `TVirtualTreeColumn` instead.

I've been looking for the help of this component but I can't find anything on how to define new columns. Could you tell me how to define new columns in this component?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I was trying to define a variable and it was not necessary. Simply add the columa directly to the tree.

```
VirtualTreeView1->Header->Columns->Add();
```